# Как создать такую кнопку с помощью СSS?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

**Здравсвтуйте!**
Есть прикрепленное изображение. Оно является кнопкой меню навигации по сайту. 
Так получилось, что при свойстве `background-size: cover;` при адаптивной верстке смещается текст из-за изменения размера блока, отведенного под кнопки. 
В итоге, я решил создать её с помощью CSS, но ума не приложу, как создать подобные "винтики" по углам, тиснение по периметру и легкий размытый белый шум. 
**Пожалуйста, помогите, буду премного благодарен!**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: :before/:after изображение для левой/правой частей

Comment: @NeedHate это именно эти болтики, да?

Comment: @Quick Brown Fox, все верно, они будут псевдо элементами.

Comment: @HamSter прописав данное значение, изображение пропало

Comment: Может быть все-таки эти винтики картинками оставить?

Comment: @VitaliyTretyakov, разницы нет, просто нужно зафиксировать их на одинаковой позиции относительно высоты и ширины при адаптиве. Чтобы изменялось положение пропорционально

Comment: Делай через `border-image`

Comment: @HamSter сделал по вашей ссылке, но при масштбаировании и изменении высоты-ширины окна, всё становится вот таким непропорциональным: https://ibb.co/ZNYRv59

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как например:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  margin: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fff;
  background: #a23b30;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #4f0c07;
  position: relative;
}


.btn>span:before,
.btn>span:after,
.btn:before,
.btn:after {
  content:'';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: url(https://cdn130.picsart.com/262053088007211.png?r1024x1024) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}

.btn>span:before,
.btn>span:after {
  bottom: 5px;
  top:auto
}

.btn>span:before,
.btn:before {
  left: 5px;
}

.btn>span:after,
.btn:after {
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="btn"><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></a>
```

Если же и сами шурупы делать средствами css, то [codepen пример](https://codepen.io/praveenpuglia/pen/mnqdf)